# How to give href to text element in d3js with zoom function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 js chart with zoom function. There are some labels on the chart. I want those labels to be clickable like href links. It looks like href is interfering with zoom function. Only either of href or zoom is working. Both are not working together. Only if I comment zoom code, href is working. And only if I comment href code, zoom is working. How to make both href and zoom working together?

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 380 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let data = [
    [95,'0.7142914222463218','#0000FF','(535/535)',0,"www.a.net"],[97,'1.5753396297416553','#00FF00','(267/267)',0,"www.b.net"],[97,'3.965827978600963','#808080','(14/14)',0,"www.c.net"],[100,'5.340348252548648','#FFAFAF','(7/8)',0,"www.d.net"],[100,'5.699038509168024','#FFAFAF','(1/8)',0,"www.e.net"],[77,'19.506535109626878','#FF0000','(5/5)',0,"www.f.net"],[77,'19.506535109626878','#FF0000','(2/2)',42,"www.g.net"]]

var SVG = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .attr("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    
   SVG.append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   
  // Add X axis
   var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, 120])
    .range([ 0, width ]);
  var xAxis = SVG.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
   
  // Add Y axis
   var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 39])
    .range([ height, 0]);
  var yAxis = SVG.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
   
  // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
   var clip = SVG.append("defs").append("SVG:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("SVG:rect")
      .attr("width", width )
      .attr("height", height )
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);
   
  // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
  var scatter = SVG.append('g')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    
  scatter
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d[0]); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function (d) { "black"; } )
      .style("opacity", 0.5);

   scatter.selectAll("a")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("a")
  //.attr({"xlink:href": "#"})
  .on("click", function() { window.open("https://google.com"); })
    .append("text")
  .attr("x", (d) => x(d[0])+d[4])
  .attr("y", (d) => y(d[1]))
  .text((d) => d[3])
  .style("fill", (d) => d[2]);

  // Set the zoom and Pan features: how much you can zoom, on which part, and what to do when there is a zoom
  var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([.5, 1000])  // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on("zoom", updateChart);

  // This add an invisible rect on top of the chart area. This rect can recover pointer events: necessary to understand when the user zoom
  SVG.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .call(zoom);
  
  // now the user can zoom and it will trigger the function called updateChart

  // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
  function updateChart() {

    // recover the new scale
    var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
    var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);

    // update axes with these new boundaries
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
    yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))

    // update circle position
    scatter
      .selectAll("circle")
      .attr('cx', function(d) {return newX(d[0])})
      .attr('cy', function(d) {return newY(d[1])});
    
    scatter.selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", (d) => newX(d[0])+d[4])
    .attr("y", (d) => newY(d[1]))
  }
//})
```

```html
<head>
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 380 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let data = [
    [95,'0.7142914222463218','#0000FF','(535/535)',0,"www.a.net"],[97,'1.5753396297416553','#00FF00','(267/267)',0,"www.b.net"],[97,'3.965827978600963','#808080','(14/14)',0,"www.c.net"],[100,'5.340348252548648','#FFAFAF','(7/8)',0,"www.d.net"],[100,'5.699038509168024','#FFAFAF','(1/8)',0,"www.e.net"],[77,'19.506535109626878','#FF0000','(5/5)',0,"www.f.net"],[77,'19.506535109626878','#FF0000','(2/2)',42,"www.g.net"]]

var SVG = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .attr("xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    
   SVG.append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   
  // Add X axis
   var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([1, 120])
    .range([ 0, width ]);
  var xAxis = SVG.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
   
  // Add Y axis
   var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 39])
    .range([ height, 0]);
  var yAxis = SVG.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
   
  // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
   var clip = SVG.append("defs").append("SVG:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("SVG:rect")
      .attr("width", width )
      .attr("height", height )
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);
   
  // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
  var scatter = SVG.append('g')
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    
  scatter
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d[0]); } )
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function (d) { "black"; } )
      .style("opacity", 0.5);

   scatter.selectAll(".textg")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr('class','textg')
  .style('cursor','pointer')
  //.attr({"xlink:href": "#"})
  .on("click", function() { window.open("https://google.com"); })
  
    .append("text")
//    .attr({x: (d) => x(d[0])+d[4], y: (d) => y(d[1])})
  .attr("x", (d) => x(d[0])+d[4])
  .attr("y", (d) => y(d[1]))
  .text((d) => d[3])
  .style("fill", (d) => d[2]);

  // Set the zoom and Pan features: how much you can zoom, on which part, and what to do when there is a zoom
  var zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([.5, 1000])  // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on("zoom", updateChart);

  // This add an invisible rect on top of the chart area. This rect can recover pointer events: necessary to understand when the user zoom
  SVG.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
      .call(zoom);
      scatter.raise()
  
  // now the user can zoom and it will trigger the function called updateChart

  // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
  function updateChart() {

    // recover the new scale
    var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
    var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);

    // update axes with these new boundaries
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
    yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))

    // update circle position
    scatter
      .selectAll("circle")
      .attr('cx', function(d) {return newX(d[0])})
      .attr('cy', function(d) {return newY(d[1])});
    
    scatter.selectAll("text")
    .attr("x", (d) => newX(d[0])+d[4])
    .attr("y", (d) => newY(d[1]))
    
      scatter.raise()
  }
//})
```

```html
<head>
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>
```

Hello, i think your problem is that `d3.zoom` is putting e rect to capture mouse events.

So one solution is to put the `<g/>` on top of the rect so you can click your elements.

Luckily d3 has an easy way to bring an element to the top:
`scatter.raise()`

Click doesn't work on sniper because you can't open a new window on snippet sandbox, however you can see the cursor change on text over